# SymPy : How to define superscripts and subscripts in the same time

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy

I want to define indexbase symbol that has superscripts and subscripts.

1. Can I do that, if yes how can I do that?

until now I wrote this :

```
c = IndexedBase('c') 
i = symbols("i", cls=Idx)
omega = symbols("omega", cls=Idx)
var_c = c[i, omega]
```

where

```
spec_cond = And(i == [1,2], omega == [1,2])
var_c = var_c.subs(spec_cond, True)
```

Comment: Do you just mean that you want the indexedbase to print differently with one index showing as a subscript and the other as a superscript?

Comment: Exactly! I have many indexes.

Comment: Your best bet is probably making a custom printer then.

Comment: I hoped somebody had done it already :). Thank you